# Extract info from CSS tag code with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some info from a site with Python's `BeautifulSoup` library. In particular  I want to extract info from this ccs code:

```
<span class="g47SY ">68</span>
```

Using `find_all` command doesn't work and I don't understand the mistake.
Can you help me?

This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.exemple.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
html_as_string = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_as_string, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.prettify())

# I want to extract 68 from <span class="g47SY ">68</span>
info = soup.find_all("span", class_="g47SY")
print (info)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! For reproducing your issue environment i might need the URL of the website you are trying to scrape. Can you provide it?

Comment: [link](https://www.instagram.com/antedoro/) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: `[span.text for span in info]`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct in terms of finding the elements on an HTML page. The problem is the Instagram page itself. If you look at its source (not the DevTools Elements panel), you’ll see that it’s almost blank. Instagram is built entirely using JavaScript—an anti-pattern, but a firmly entrenched one—so the elements you’re looking for only exist in the client after the JavaScript has run.

You can do this using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which basically opens the site in a browser and does everything a normal browser would do. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# initialization
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/antedoro/")

try:
    # wait up to 10 seconds for the parent of the spans to be present
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Y8-fY")))
    # locate the spans
    spans = driver.find_elements_by_css_selectors("span.g47SY")
    text_of_spans = [span.text for span in spans]
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. But is there no way to scrape the instagram website?

Comment: I’ve added a Selenium example.

Comment: Apart from selenium?

Comment: Probably Headless Chrome, but I haven’t used it myself.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like that’s done through Selenium too.

Comment: I know there are Instagram APIs but  I was just testing beautyfulsoap library. That's okay. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` returns a list, so you need to select the first item. Then use the `text` property. Like this:

```
# I want to extract 68 from <span class="g47SY ">68</span>
info = soup.find_all("span", class_="g47SY")
print(info[0].text)
```

(Why the downvote? I just tested it, works in bs4)

Comment: The error is not because of list. He is trying to get data from instagram with requests just like that. The error arouse because the soup is None. You need to help him with that.

Comment: His question was how to extract "68" from the HTML `<span class="g47SY ">68</span>`, and that is the question I answered. Downvoting a correct answer is bad style.

Comment: I down voted because, the fix you have given is also going to throw error for him. In which way it is supportive?

Comment: @SmashGuy It does not, I tested it before I replied. It aswers the question OP asked. But its your choice to randomly downvote correct answers, if that is the kind of community you are hoping SO to be.

Comment: I apologize as i assumed you answered without testing it.

Comment: @t.m.adam I can't unless he makes any edit in his answer.

Comment: @t.m.adam Neither do I!

Comment: @SmashGuy perhaps the question has changed since the original posting, but where does it say in the OP that he's getting info from Instagram? He provides a one-liner of HTML code and asks how to get the text. Seems that what he answered.